# Retrofit2 downloaded image inputstream can't be decoded?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I am using Retrofit2 to download image, and I do get the response from server, however the content can't be decoded as png file.

Here is the code I used to decode the stream to png.

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
        InputStream input = response.body().byteStream();
        String avatarPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath()+ "/downloaded.png";
        try {
            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(avatarPath);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream); // bmp is your Bitmap instance
            input.close();
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.v("download  -------", "success");
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.v("download -------", "failed");
    }
 });
```

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
here bitmap is null, seems the inputstream can't be recognized as png.

I don't know how to decode correctly the png file from the InputStream, here I found one thing the original png size was 21.6K, however from the InputStream I can see the buffer size is 37.6K, maybe I need to find the proper way to decode the inputstream png.

could anyone help?